# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, Datum[], string | number | boolean | null>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and tried to implement a minimal line chart using d3, TypeScript and react. But it will always result in a TypeScript error. I even see my chart for a split second before it gets replaced by the error message.

I separated the d3 part from the react code as much as possible. There is a react component that renders a `div` with an `id` and at `componentDidUpdate` the `id` gets passed to a `draw` function in a separate file with all my d3 code (code below).
I tried to provide a type for everything that can be typed.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'

type Props = { id: string }
type Datum = {x: number, y: number}
type Data = Array<Datum>

const draw = (props: Props) => {
    const data = [
        { x: 1, y: 5 },
        { x: 20, y: 20 },
        { x: 40, y: 10 },
        { x: 60, y: 40 },
        { x: 80, y: 5 },
        { x: 100, y: 60 },
    ]
    const container = d3.select<HTMLElement, any>('#' + props.id)
    container.selectAll<HTMLElement, any>('*').remove()
    const svg = container.append<SVGElement>('svg')
    const lineGenerator = d3.line<Datum>()
        .x((d: Datum) => d.x)
        .y((d: Datum) => d.y)

    svg.append<SVGPathElement>('path')
        .datum<Data>(data)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
        .attr('d', lineGenerator(data))
}

export default draw
```

Like I said, the chart is visible but quickly disappears and instead I get:

> ...
>  TypeScript error in ... :
>   Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, Datum[], string | number | boolean |
>   null>'.
>       Type 'null' is not assignable to type
>   'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, Datum[], string | number | boolean | null>'. 
>   TS2345
>
> ```
>     26 |         .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
>     27 |         .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
>   > 28 |         .attr('d', lineGenerator(data))
>        |                    ^
>     29 | }
>     30 | 
>     31 | export default draw
> ```

Any ideas where the `argument of type string | null` comes from and how to fix that error?

EDIT: Since it turned out not to be related to the problem, I removed the react code for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is the TypeScript equivalent of various types of JavaScript questions that pop up every now and then where the developer confuses passing a function by reference with calling said function in situ whereby just passing its return value.

You are actually calling, i.e. executing, the line generator by doing `lineGenerator(data)`. As you can see from the API [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#_line) and the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-shape/index.d.ts#L663) this will return either a string or null:

```
export interface Line<Datum> {
  (data: Datum[]): string | null;
  //...
}
```

This does not match the signature of the [.attr()](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L293) method, though, which in this case expects a function to be passed as the second argument.

```
export interface Selection<GElement extends BaseType, Datum, PElement extends BaseType, PDatum> {
  //...
  attr(name: string, value: ValueFn<GElement, Datum, string | number | boolean | null>): this;
  //...
}
```

The solution is to pass the generator to `.attr()` without executing it:

```
.attr('d', lineGenerator)
```

The generator will then be executed by the inner workings of `.attr()` being passed the data bound to the selection. That, in turn, will return the path definition string for the `d` attribute of the path.